# BEGINNER indentation issues in Python 3.3 Interactive Shell IDLE

Tags: python, conditional-statements, python-idle

I am having what appears to be indentation issues in the Python Interactive Shell IDLE for Python version 3.3 64 bit on a Windows 7 Professional 64bit computer. This is the idea behind simple conditional flow program I am trying to write:

```
if spam == 1:
    print('Hello')
elif spam == 2:
    print('Howdy')
else:
    print('Greetings!")
```

The interactive shell is not letting the "elif" return to the same block (not sure if I am describing that correctly) as the if statement, so it ends up looking like this:

```
if spam == 1:
    print('Hello')
elif spam == 2:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
if spam == 1:
    print('Hello')
    elif spam == 2:

SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
>>>
```

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Recommendation: don't write code in the interactive shell. Write it in a code window and then *test* it in the shell. Writing structured code in the interactive IDLE shell is a pain and the time spent in fixing indentation errors due to it just isn't worth it. The editor in an IDLE code window handles indentation in a much saner way.

Comment: The only syntax problem in your code is the mismatched quotation marks in 'Greetings!".  You're also missing a definition for **spam**.  With those problems fixed, this runs.

Comment: I mostly just type simple statements at the >>> prompt.  I have a couple of scratch files that I usually use for anything more than, say, 3 lines.  Since I use them frequently, they are usually listed in and easily accessed via the `Recent Files` list.

Comment: Are you taking a class that forces 3.3?  There have been numerous bug fixes and enhancements to IDLE since then.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy The idea of a scratch file is a good one which might not occur to many newbies. It took me over a year of Python programming to hit upon the idea. Before I did so, I tended to write anything that I didn't intend to keep in the shell but sometimes ran into the same issues that OP faces. Now I just use my handy `test.py` which is typically #2 or 3 on my recent files list.

Comment: Just figured out how to run new file and test in the interactive shell.  I am taking a class that references 3.3 on web scraping, working with excel, word, and PDF.  Justlearning the basics at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The interactive shell's prompt, `>>>`, does take up space visually, but it is not considered code. Code at the same indentation level as a line that includes a prompt should begin where the prompt begins, not where your code begins.

```
>>> if 1==1:
    pass
else:
    pass

>>>
```

If you start the interpreter from your system's terminal (e.g. cmd, PowerShell, etc.), there is a different prompt, `...`, for subsequent lines in a block, providing a clearer representation of your code:

```
>>> if 1==1:
...     pass
... else:
...     pass
...
>>>
```